# Is it possible to interrupt finish()

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I have an activity running in SingleTask mode (Android 2.2) which receives intents from other activities or services. My activity pushes each received intent into a queue and does something with it. On completion, if there isn't any intent left to process (i.e. the queue is empty) it calls finish().

The problem is when it receives an intent immediately after finish() has been called: the onNewIntent and onResume methods are called, but my activity is then destroyed (onPause/onDestroy) by Android and the intent is not processed.

I know that this is quite a naughty scenario, but I'm interested in this kind of behaviour... so the question is: is it possible to interrupt finish() and/or resume the activity after finish() has been called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to re-create an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Answer (score 0):

on call to finish() the onDestroy() method is called and than you activity is dead :)

this activity can be started again by some intent, but the oncreate will be called not onNewIntent

Important note is that the intent can not be received between the finish() statement and onDrestroy method !

so if the finish is called then every new intent for your activity will result with call to onCreate()

so you do not to be worried

you should not try to interrupt finish that is not possible cause it is atomic operation
But you need to review you logic and enhance your oncreate and onNewIntent method to gracefully handle your scenario

Comment: > the intent can not be received between the finish() statement and onDrestroy method
This is not correct: finish() triggers a call to ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().finishActivity(), which calls onPause and onDestroy asynchronously, and Intents can indeed be received between these two methods, at least on Android 2.2 (it's my situation). As I wrote, after calling finish() I see that onNewIntent() is executed, followed by onResume(). Then onPause() and onDestroy() are called by ActivityManagerNative.

Answer (score 0):

Start activity from onNewIntent.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    if (isFinishing()) {
        // Start the activity again using the new intent
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
}
```